# How can i send data to phpmyadmin database? using esp8266 nodemcu and max30100

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

i want to send data from my sensor to database phpmyadmin. but i only get zero values. please help me thank you.

```
void loop()
{
  pox.update();
  BPM = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
 // Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(BPM);

  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    Serial.print("BPM: ");
    Serial.println(BPM);
    Serial.print("SpO2: ");
    Serial.print(SpO2);
    Serial.println("%");
    Serial.println("*********************************");
    Serial.println();
    tsLastReport = millis();
    delay(0); 
    }
    Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(BPM);
}

void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(float BPM){
  if (client.connect(server_addr,80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    Serial.print("GET /pulse.php?BPM=12");
    client.print("GET /pulse.php?pox.getHeartRate="+String(BPM,1));
    Serial.println("pox.getHeartRate!");
    client.println("pulse="); 
    client.println(BPM);
   // Serial.print("GET /vsmonitor/connect.php?SpO2=12");
   // client.print("GET /vsmonitor/connect.php?SpO2="+String(SpO2,1));
   // Serial.println("SpO2!");
    //client.println("o2_sat="); 
    //client.println(SpO2);
    client.print(" ");
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1"); 
    client.println("Host: 192.168.15.4");
    client.println(server_addr);
    client.println("Connection: close"); 
    client.println(); 
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
  }
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: so, where is the problem? ... you have a bunch of `Serial.print()` functions ... why did you not say what is being printed?

Comment: your question is like `i want to boil water from a well, but i can't` ... several scenarios are possible ... no water in well, no bucket to carry water, no pot to boil water, no  stove, no gas for fire, no electricity .... i think that you get the idea

Comment: the problem starts when i call the void Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(BPM);. i get zero values. example BPM 0.0 in serial monitor. and in database is 0

Comment: Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(BPM); slowers down m output i dont know why, it works perfectl when i remove the Sending_To_phpmyadmindatabase(BPM);.

Comment: remove ln from the second url parameter prints. and what should `client.print(" ");` do?

Comment: @CodeGorilla, do some research into how HTTP GET requests work. They're really useful. Don't be fooled by the name "GET". A GET request "gets" a URL from the web server, receiving data in return or just a simple acknowledgement, but also offering the opportunity of sending data from the client as part of the URL parameters (like ?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2 etc.). It's often the simplest way of sending small amounts of data to a web server.